# I'm working on Django project Asynchronous with Uvicorn async view

Tags: python, django, backend, software-design

- python==3.11.3
- asgiref==3.6.0
- Django==4.1.8

---

I'm working on Django project Asynchronous with Uvicorn async view.
all the building books is fine
but when I call the post build it create the book but show's this problem
but after refreshing the page again it showin

---

`TypeError at /builds/ sync_to_async can only be applied to sync functions.`

`

```
import re
from subprocess import check_output

from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View

from crayon.books.models import Book
from crayon.builds.models import Build
from crayon.core.mixin import AsyncViewMixin

class AsyncViewMixin:
    async def __call__(self):
        return super().__call__(self)

def build_book(book_id: int, user_id: int) -> str:
    global document, build
    # step 1: Get the book
    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id, creator_id=user_id)
    # step 2: compile the book's contents
    build = Build.objects.create(builder_id=user_id, book_id=book_id)
    build.status = Build.STATUS.IN_PROGRESS
    build.save()
    document_list = []
    for chapter in book.chapter_set.all():
        document_list.append(f"# {chapter.title}")
        # If a "reges" finds an markdown H1
        if re.search(r"\n\#\s", chapter.body) or re.match("\#\s", chapter.body):
            chapter.body = add_pound_to_headers(chapter.body)
        document_list.append(chapter.body)
    document = "\n\n".join(document_list)
    # step 3: render as something using pandoc
    # Pandoc -o book.html input.md
    with open("input.md", "w") as f:
        f.write(document)
    commands = ["pandoc", "-o", "book.html", "input.md"]
    output = check_output(commands)
    return output

class BuildView(LoginRequiredMixin, AsyncViewMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # If without ID then shows list of builds for user
        # If with ID then show details
        return render(request, "builds/build.html", {})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Step 1: get the book
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=self.request.POST["book_id"], creator=request.user.id)
        # accept a form request asking for a build
        sync_to_async(build_book(book_id=book.id, user_id=request.user.id))
        return redirect("books:update", pk=request.POST["book_id"])
```